# rename() gives undocumented return value NULL

Tags: php, php-7.2

After an update from PHP7.0 to PHP7.2 some code stopped working and I don't understand why:

```
$res = rename($tmpfile, $output_file);
if ($res !== true) {
   throw new Exception("Unable to rename temporary file");
}
```

In php7.2 the exception is triggered, although the rename was successfully done, the file is perfectly readable and nothing has gone wrong. Still I get the exception, because the return value is NULL. I inserted some debugging code:

```
$res = rename($tmpfile, $output_file);
log('Debug: $res ' . $res);
log('Debug: $res true? ' . $res === true);
log('Debug: $res type ' . gettype($res));
if ($res !== true) {
    throw new Exception("Unable to rename temporary file");
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
2018-08-03 10:37:39 Debug: $res 
2018-08-03 10:37:39 
2018-08-03 10:37:39 Debug: $res type NULL
2018-08-03 10:37:39 CURL_DOWNLOAD Exception: Unable to rename temporary file
#0 /var/www/formr.org/application/Library/Functions.php(1470): CURL::DownloadUrl('http://docs.goo...', '/var/www/formr....', NULL, 'GET', Array, Array)
```

As you can see, there is no output, and the type is NULL. That is an undocumented behavior. [According to the php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php#refsect1-function.rename-returnvalues) the return value must be nothing but true or false.

I couldn't find any documentation that the behavior of this function was changed. Does someone understand this?

Thanks for help!

Edit: var_dump output

```
$res = rename($tmpfile, $output_file);
ob_start();
var_dump($res);
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
log('Debug $res: ' . $contents);
```

Gives:

```
2018-08-03 12:37:40 Debug $res: NULL
```

Testing rename()-function in terminal:

```
user$ sudo su www-data -s /bin/bash
www-data$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $old='/var/www/path/changed/filename.xlsx';
php > $new='/var/www/path/changed/newfilename.xlsx';
php > $res = rename($old, $new);
php > var_dump($res);
bool(true)
```

(I changed the filenname and path for privacy reasons, but I tested it on the original file.)

PHP version:

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.2.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (cli) (built: Jul  4 2018 16:55:24) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

The PHP version installed is the one that comes shipped with Ubuntu 18.04. I didn't recompile it myself.

The program has its own rename functions, at two times, as I just noticed. But they are not about renaming files, they rename something in the database.

They both have just one parameter. PHP does not support overloading or differentiation by number of arguments, so might there be some interference? So far this hasn't been an issue. And as the file is actually renamed, I don't believe that the wrong function is called.

Comment: Simple `var_dump($res)` shows what?

Comment: That does sound weird. Only thing that I can think of is that the execution of the function `rename()` breaks somewhere after the actual renaming and before returning. Have you tried this with different inputs to see if it consistently happens?

Comment: I added the output of var_dump in my post. It gives NULL.

Comment: Can it be that you have installed some bad version of PHP and it has modified `rename` function?

Comment: I upated the post, inserted the manual rename, php version etc.

Comment: *The program has its own rename functions*. PHP does not support function overloading but you can still get namespaced functions so to be sure you're calling the right rename you can do `\rename(a,b)`

Comment: This indeed fixes the problem! Awesome. Thanks

Comment: Do you know, in which way this was changed between PHP7.0 and PHP7.2? I'd like to read more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by last comment of Apokryfos: Properly calling the rename-function with namespace `\rename($old,$new)` gives me `bool(true)` as return value.